# How to decode an extended $[16,11]$Hamming code?

Tags: coding-theory

How to decode an extended $[16,11]$Hamming code?

As you may know, by adding one parity-check bit to the end of codewords of $[15,11]$Hamming code (or equivalently by adding an all zero column and an all one row to its parity-check matrix). Decoding of Lexicographic $[15,11]$Hamming code is so easy, but how about $[16,11]$Hamming code?

I simulated

I compared bit error rate (with respect to $E_b/N_0$) for $[15,11]$Hamming code, $[16,11]$extended Hamming code , and $[14,10]$ shortened Hamming code using BPSK over AWGN channel. Does the below figure seem correct?
[image]

Comment: Essentially answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/482117/15941).

Comment: In that answer it is presumed that the two-bit errors are adjacent, but I am looking for a general decoding scheme (e.g. based on syndrome table). For the case of syndrome table if we assume all errors of weight at most 1 are selected as coset leaders, and the leader of the left cosets are to be selected from errors of weight two, does BER depend on the selection of leader of the remaining cosets? How to make BER minimum by the freedom available?

Comment: All words of least weight in a coset are potential coset leaders. As you correctly say, cosets with minimum weights 0 and 1 have unique coset leaders. If the channel bit errors are independent, it makes no difference which bit error patterns of weight 2 are chosen as coset leaders; the BER is the same regardless of the choice.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks for your answer. I want to compare bit error rate (with respect to $E_b/N_0$) for $[15,11]$Hamming code, $[16,11]$extended Hamming code , and $[14,10]$ shortened Hamming code using BPSK over AWGN channel. What I am supposed to get? How they perform for moderate SNRs?

Comment: The expectation depends how you decode with the (16,11) code. If you make hard decisions for individual bits, and don't do anything with weight two cosets, then you have essentially just tagged along a dead weight extra bit. You could try to do some minimal soft decision decoding by making a second decoding attempt (if the first fails) by first flipping the least reliable bit. If you want to milk everything out of this code, you could use its [trellis representation](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/158624/11619). Admittedlt it is doubtful that you would have covered that bit of theory yet.